# How to hide out of stock notifications unless logged into NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to hide out of stock notifications to only those users who are logged into our NetSuite website.

we currently have all items set to "allow backorders and show out of stock message", which corresponds to the second "if" clause:

```
<div class="item-views-stock">
{{#if isAvailableInStore}}
    <div class='item-views-stock-msg-not-available'>{{translate 'This item is no longer available'}}</div>
{{else}}
    {{#if showOutOfStockMessage}}
        <p class="item-views-stock-msg-out">
            <span class="item-views-stock-icon-out">
                <i></i> 
            </span>
            <span class="item-views-stock-msg-out-text">{{stockInfo.outOfStockMessage}}</span>
        </p>
        {{/if}}
    {{#if showInStockMessage}}
        <p class="item-views-stock-msg-in">
            <span class="item-views-stock-icon-in">
                <i></i>
            </span>
            {{stockInfo.inStockMessage}}
        </p>
    {{/if}}
    {{#if showStockDescription}}
        <p class="item-views-stock-msg-description {{stockInfo.stockDescriptionClass}}">
            <i class="item-views-stock-icon-description"></i>
            {{stockInfo.stockDescription}}
        </p>
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

does anyone have any idea how to do this? I thought I could add the following if statement, but it doesn't seem to work properly:

{{#if isPriceEnabled}}

then show out of stock message

{{/if}}

EDIT:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERwRx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isPriceEnabled` needs to be defined in template's context in order to be used in the template. If you are using item_views_stock template modify your ItemViews.Stock.View `getContext`:

```
getContext: function ()
        {
            ...

            return {
                ...

                isPriceEnabled: !ProfileModel.getInstance().hidePrices()
            };
        }
```

If you need to check if the user is logged into your site you can also try using:

```
isLoggedIn: ProfileModel.getInstance().get('isLoggedIn') === 'T'
```

Both approaches need `Profile.Model` required in your view.

Comment: so I've tried both 'isPriceEnabled' and 'isLoggedIn', but I must be doing something wrong. Neither will achieve the desired effect of hiding 'out-of-stock' messages to users who aren't logged in. Are you able to provide more details on how to proceed?

Comment: Are you passing 'Profile.Model' to the dependencies array: `define('ItemViews.Stock.View',[..., 'Profile.Model']` and then as an argument to the factory function `function(item_views_stock_tpl,...,ProfileModel)`? Once you have ProfileModel defined, you can add the `isLoggedIn` property to the return of `getContext` function. In your template use `{{#if isLoggedIn}}...{{/if}}`

Comment: Yes, but I'm still trying to get everything to work. Should I wrap the entire template in the if statement, or place it before the second clause? Sorry, please bear with me as I'm not a programmer by trade.

Comment: can you have a look at the image and let me know what I'm missing?

Comment: Remove the dot from `Profile.Model` in your function arguments. It should look like this: `function(item_views_stock_tpl, Backbone, _, ProfileModel)`

Comment: it's ... not ... working. I'm not sure what's happening but it doesn't seem to be working properly. if I turn it on and add the code, the site doesn't show the OOS message at all. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: @yangbanger only logged in users can see the OOS with this logic. If you need to hide OOS message for logged in users you can change the logged in property: `notLoggedIn: !(ProfileModel.getInstance().get('isLoggedIn') === 'T')` If it is still not working you can try to add some logs to find out what's wrong

Comment: someone from NetSuite just posted this on their forums: " 'isLoggedIn' method is no longer supported or recommended. This method works correctly in the Checkout domain but may return false when used in the Shopping domain even when the user is logged in. The method is currently being use in pre_Denali versions of SuiteCommerce Advanced. If you encounter session issues in those bundles, contact support to migrate to using the isLoggedIn2() method."

Comment: @yangbanger `isLoggedIn2` is used in backend scripts. `IsLoggedIn` property from Profile Model is populated with `isLoggedIn2` when the profile is bootstrapped. I think that you are having issues with 'recognized' users. If the user had logged in and then closed the browser, `isLoggedIn` will be false but `isRecognized` will be true when he returns to your site, that's because it looks like the user is logged into your site. You could try to hide your stock message if `ProfileModel.getInstance().get('isLoggedIn') === 'F' && ProfileModel.getInstance().get('isRecognized') === 'F'`

Comment: @yangbanger Anonymous user: isRecognized() == false and isLoggedIn() == false, logged in user: isRecognized() == true and isLoggedIn() == true, user who clicked logout: isRecognized() == false and isLoggedIn() == false, user who had logged in, then closed his browser and later returns: isRecognized() == true and isLoggedIn() == false